# Why is the Instantiate (this, ...) call different from when it is debugging?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got help from a translator because I am not good at English. :<

While studying the Unity C# script, i noticed the following problems:

In debugging mode, if you enter breakpoints in a specific location, the script behaves differently than I think it would.
(GameObject will continue to be create.)

If you do not enter a breakpoint, it will function normally without any problems.
(Only once.)

How do we know what's going on here?

I using unity version 2019.2.10f1 Personal.

```
public class Sample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool instantiate = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (instantiate)
            return;

        // if check breakpoints, create continues gameobject...
        Instantiate(this, transform.parent).instantiate = true;
    }
}
```

```
public class Sample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool instantiate = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (instantiate)
            return;

        // The code below is fine.
        var temp = Instantiate(this, transform.parent);
        temp.instantiate = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating the script infinite number of times. Every time you instantiate the script, it calls the Start function in the instantiated script that then call instantiate again. That calls Start again and so on.
I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you would change the instantiate variable to static it would work.

Comment: @SagiZiv
I asked the question because I was curious about the difference between debugging and not.
If the Start function is a recursive call, I wanted to understand that the behavior should be the same when it is not debugged, but only if it is taken a break point, the results are different.